# Notifications plugin - what to use

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Which is the best plugin available for sending notifications on the Grails application. I tried to use the notification plugin compile ":notifications:0.2.6" but while running it is showing error-:

```
|Loading Grails 2.5.0
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
|Installing zip notifications-0.2.6.zip...
...
|Installed plugin notifications-0.2.6
.....................
|Compiling 122 source files
Note: C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\scaffolding-2.1.2\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\scaffolding\AbstractGrailsTemplateGenerator.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\MailManager.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
  [groovyc]  @ line 7, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\MailManager.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.mail.MailService
  [groovyc]  @ line 5, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import grails.plugin.mail.MailService
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\MailManager.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.mail.MailService 
  [groovyc]  @ line 12, column 3.
  [groovyc]     private MailService service
  [groovyc]     ^
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\config\NotificationUtils.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
  [groovyc]  @ line 3, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\custom\CustomMailNotification.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
  [groovyc]  @ line 7, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\custom\CustomMailNotification.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.mail.MailService
  [groovyc]  @ line 6, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import grails.plugin.mail.MailService
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\custom\CustomMailNotification.groovy: 13: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.mail.MailService 
  [groovyc]  @ line 13, column 3.
  [groovyc]     private MailService service
  [groovyc]     ^
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] 7 errors

.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\MailManager.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
 @ line 7, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
   ^
C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\MailManager.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.mail.MailService
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import grails.plugin.mail.MailService
   ^
C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\MailManager.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.mail.MailService 
 @ line 12, column 3.
    private MailService service
    ^
C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\config\NotificationUtils.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH
   ^
C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\custom\CustomMailNotification.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
 @ line 7, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
   ^
C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\custom\CustomMailNotification.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.mail.MailService
 @ line 6, column 1.
   import grails.plugin.mail.MailService
   ^
C:\Users\DELL-PC\git\haribol-part2\tearp\target\work\plugins\notifications-0.2.6\src\groovy\pt\whiteroad\plugins\notifications\custom\CustomMailNotification.groovy: 13: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.mail.MailService 
 @ line 13, column 3.
    private MailService service
    ^
7 errors
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score -1):

The notifications plugin is quite old and presumably is not compatible with the version of Grails you are using. Try the mail plugin https://grails.org/plugin/mail

Comment: https://grails.org/plugin/mail is for sending emails not notifications.